# Index structure to maximize speed across any combination of index columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a database with about five possible index columns, all of which are useful in different ways.  Let's call them System, Source, Heat, Time, and Row.  Using System and Row together will make a unique key, and if sorted by System-Row the database will also be sorted for any combination of the five index variables (in the order I listed them above).

My problem is that I use all combinations of these columns: sometimes I want to JOIN each System-Row to the next System-(Row+1), sometimes I want to GROUP or WHERE by System-Source-Heat, sometimes I want to look at all entries of System-Source WHERE Time is in a specific window, etc.

Basically, I want an index structure that functions similarly to every possible permutation of those five indexes (in the correct order, of course), without actually making every permutation (although I am willing to do so if necessary).  I'm doing statistics / analytics, not traditional database work, so the size of the index and speed of creating / updating it is not a concern; I only care about speeding my improvised queries as I tend to think them up, run them, wait 5-10 minutes, and then never use them again.  Thus my main concern is reducing the "wait 5-10 minutes" to something more like "wait 1-2 minutes."

My sorted data would look something like this:

```
Sys So H Ti R
1   1  0 .1 1
1   1  1 .2 2
1   1  1 .3 3
1   1  2 .3 4
1   2  0 .5 5
1   2  0 .6 6
1   2  1 .8 7
1   2  2 .8 8
```

EDIT: It may simplify things a bit that System virtually always needs to be included as the first column to make any of the other 4 columns in sorted order.

Comment: Not exactly the same situation but similar, check this, too: **[Do I risk losing the benefits of indexing if I have an index on every column?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27949/do-i-risk-losing-the-benefits-of-indexing-if-i-have-an-index-on-every-column)**

Comment: You need to determine whether you can sacrifice performance when performing CUD statements with respect to your query execution time. Have you looked into creating a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for taking a while to get back to this, I had to work on something else for a few weeks.  Anyway, after trying a bunch of things (including everything suggested here, even the brute-force "make an index for every permutation" method), I haven't found any indexing method that significantly improves performance.

However, I HAVE found an alternate, non-indexing solution: selecting only the rows and columns I'm interested in into intermediary tables, and then working with those instead of the complete table (so I use about 5 mil rows of 6 cols instead of 30 mil rows of 35 cols).  The initial select and table creation is a bit slow, but the steps after that are so much faster I actually save time even if I only run it once (and considering how often I change things, it's usually much more than once).

I have a suspicion that the reason for this vast improvement will be obvious to most SQL users (probably something about pagefile size), and I apologize if so.  My only excuse is that I'm a statistician trying to teach myself how to do this as I go, and while I'm pretty decent at getting what I want done to happen (eventually), my understanding of the mechanics of *how* it's being done are distressingly close to "it's a magic black box, don't worry about it."

Answer (score 0):

If you are **ONLY** concerned with SELECT speed and don't care about INSERT, then you can materialize ALL the combinations as INDEXED views. You only need 24 times the storage of the original table, making one table and 23 INDEXED VIEWs of 5 columns each.

e.g.

```
create table data (
    id int identity primary key clustered,
    sys int,
    so int,
    h float,
    ti datetime,
    r int);
GO
create view dbo.data_v1 with schemabinding as
    select sys, so, h, ti, r
    from dbo.data;
GO
create unique clustered index cix_data_v1 on data_v1(sys, h, ti, r, so)
GO
create view dbo.data_v2 with schemabinding as
    select sys, so, h, ti, r
    from dbo.data;
GO
create unique clustered index cix_data_v2 on data_v2(sys, ti, r, so, h)
GO

-- and so on and so forth, keeping "sys" anchored at the front
```

Do note, however
[Q. Why isn't my indexed view being picked up by the query optimizer for use in the query plan?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (search within linked article)

---

If space IS an issue, then the next best thing is to create individual indexes on each of the 4 columns, leading with system, i.e. (sys,ti), (sys,r) etc.  These can be used together if it will help the query, otherwise it will revert to a full table scan.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected: space _may be_ an issue.  If my collection of indexes are 2-3 times the original table size it's not a big deal, but 24 times would start getting into TB range.  Also, I'm not sure if this solves the problem of a system-source-heat index not helping a search based only on system-source.

Comment: Space aside, `system-source-heat-time` **does** help a `system-source` query. It may not be as efficient as a `system-source-heat` or `system-source` index, but being a clustered index it could just edge one or both out, definitely if you're querying on 2 columns but retrieving others as well.